# How can I load a header, change it, then redirect to a page with the updated header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 html documents: `header.html`, `blackPage.html`, and `greenPage.html`. `header.html` is common to both `blackPage.html` and `greenPage.html`. I want to make it so that a button in the header, used to change pages, reflects the color of the current page using a script called `HeaderScript.js`. How should I go about doing this? (This is just an example: in the real application, the green page won't have enough info on it to determine what the header should be, so I can't just update it when I load the green page).

Here are the 4 files I'm using:

### header.html

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src=HeaderScript.js></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Button").click(function(){
                changePage($("#Button").get(0));
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #Button {
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="Button"></div>
</html>
```

### blackPage.html

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Header").load("header.html");
        });
    </script>

    <Title>Black Page</Title>
    <h>Black Page</h>

    <div id="Header"></div>
</html>
```

### greenPage.html

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Header").load("header.html");
        });
    </script>

    <Title>Green Page</Title>
    <h>Green Page</h>

    <div id="Header"></div>
 </html>
```

### HeaderScript.js

```
function changePage(div){
    if (div.style.backgroundColor === "green"){
        div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        alert("Color changed to black");
        document.location.href = "blackPage.html";
    }
    else{
        div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        alert("Color changed to green");
        document.location.href = "greenPage.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: @ThatWeirdo I want the header.html file to change for the user (the original should be the same), and I want them to go to a new page.

Comment: When you enter the green page, what should be the button's color? and when you press it, does its color change immediately before moving to the second page?

Comment: @ThatWeirdo When you enter the green page it should be green, and when you enter the black page it should be black. I'm not particularly concerned about when it changes yet, but before moving would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

New `header.html` page code:

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script src="HeaderScript.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var path = window.location.pathname;
            path = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                       path.indexOf('Page.html') - path.lastIndexOf('/') - 1);
            $("#Button").css('background-color', path);

            $("#Button").click(function(){
                path = (path == 'green' ? 'black' : 'green');
                $("#Button").css('background-color', path);
                window.location = path + 'Page.html';
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #Button {
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="Button"></div>
</html>
```

Hope that works ;)
Let me know..

Comment: I can't test it right now, but that looks like it would work. However, the information I want to send is not in greenPage.html or blackPage.html in the actual site, as it is in this example. The information is only in the javascript file, and I need to write it to a local instance of header.html. I did some more research and it looks like I'll have to make a cookie or use the html5 local storage feature.

Comment: Or you can POST data. If you can elaborate I may be able to help. What do you mean by information you want to send? Is it something you want to transfer between two pages?

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to the actual page source right now, but I have a menu that moves buttons around. The only information thats changing in the header is the order of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

ThatWeirdo's answer works, and his answer makes the color load before the page changes (as opposed to this solution), but I need to do it differently for the specific problem for which this question was just an example (my original code was garbage, so I made this example to try to make it simpler/clearer).

Here is what I'm going to end up doing (this assumes blackPage.html is always the first page loaded):

### header.html

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src=HeaderScript.js></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //--ADDED--
            var buttonColor = localStorage.buttonColor;
            if(buttonColor !== undefined){
                $("#Button").css("background-color", buttonColor);
            }
            //----

            $("#Button").click(function(){
                changePage($("#Button").get(0));
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #Button {
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="Button"></div>
</html>
```

### HeaderScript.js

```
function changePage(div){
    if (localStorage.buttonColor === "green"){ //CHANGED
        localStorage.buttonColor = "black"; //CHANGED
        alert("Color changed to black");
        document.location.href = "blackPage.html";
    }
    else{
        localStorage.buttonColor = "green"; //CHANGED
        alert("Color changed to green");
        document.location.href = "greenPage.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the `changePag` function need the button?
You can just test for the current value of the saved color in storage.

Comment: @ThatWeirdo Yep, absolutely right. I'll change that.